# "treating the interference as noise" or "treating interference as noise"?

Tags: grammaticality, definite-articles

Which one is the proper term to use when talking about interference in wireless networks "treating the interference as noise" or "treating interference as noise"?

When I check google scholars the second one is used more, but it seems we need "the" there.

Example: While treating interference as noise is optimal in some scenarios, decoding interference is optimal in others.

Comment: Please can you clarify whether you're referring to some particular interference (or interference that occurs in some specified situation), or interference in general. This will determine whether to use "the" or not.

Comment: As @chasly suggests, it depends on what you mean.  Without "the" you are referring to all interference.  With "the" you are referring to some specific interference (presumably from a source that was previously discussed).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"the interference" refers to some known, previously mentioned interference (e.g. *atmospheric interference* or *general interference*)

"interference" means "any interference that may exist"